# How to export and import ES6 class in iojs?

Tags: class, ecmascript-6, iojs

In **foo.js**

```
class Foo {
    run(){
        console.log("test");
    }
}
```

In **index.js**

```
'use strict'    

var test = require('./foo.js'),
    Test = new test();

Test.run();
```

How to export the Foo class in iojs 3?

I tryed this way and worked, but i dont know if this is the right way:

```
module.exports = class Foo {
                    run(){
                        console.log("test");
                    }
                 }
```

Comment: Are you using a transpiler? iojs doesn't support ES6 module import/export so that will drastically affect the answer.

Comment: no transpiler, just iojs and ES6

Comment: Then yeah, your last example is fine. A class is no different from anything else if you're using standard CommonJS module.

Comment: maybe doing this way... in future when iojs support import/export, just change the way how the code import things.

Answer (score 0):

In current io.js you can do something like this to get your class exported so it can be imported with require():

```
'use strict'


class Foo {

}

module.exports = Foo;
```

and

```
const Foo = require('./foo');
```